# Text Within Ng-include Doesn't Highlight

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a div inside an ng-include template that won't highlight when you mouse over. The cursor does change to a pointer on hovering over the text, but when you actually click and drag to highlight the text, nothing highlights.

This is important because I can't tab through the elements inside the ng-included template, which is a requirement for screen readability. Any ideas what's going on?

Parent template:

```
<div ng-controller="EntryController">
    <!-- Stuff that works -->
    <div ng-include="'entry_review.html'"></div>
</div>
```

entry_review.html:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

Result - not able to click and drag a highlight over "hello". Also can't tab through it (which is the real problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has 'user-select: none;' somewhere in the CSS?

Angular shouldn't have any affect on this.

Comment: Thanks! I found a mysterious bit in my css that was setting user-select to none. No idea why. Still not able to tab through the elements though, any ideas why? I'm not sure what CSS controls tabbing.

Comment: If you make it an "a" tag instead of div you'll be able to tab to it.  The other option could be to use the "tabindex" attribute.

Comment: I used the tabindex attribute and it worked, thanks!